# PHP Find & Replace where url and extension

Tags: php, html

I've been looking for an example on how to use preg_replace or RegEX to

search HTML for either http://www.mydomain.co.uk/page.html or /page.html

and replace .html with .app

I only want to replace the .html on pages that belong to this site

I have an app that uses pages from our website. When I link page from the app I put .app so it removes/ changes the formatting. Which works, I just want to dynamically edit the links on the pages.

Cheers

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Do you wan't to do that on the server side ? What did you try ? Some code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK for those interested, I've cracked it. 
It searches html for links then checks if the link belongs to site. 
Find ".html" replace with ".app" within the link 
Find old links replace with new links within html.

Thanks guys you pointed me in the right direction

```
function searchHTML($html){
// if the page is used by the app replace all domain pages .html with .app

        $domain ='mydomain.com';
        $regEX = '/<a[^>]+href=([\'"])(.+?)\1[^>]*>/I';
        preg_match_all($regEX, $html, $match); //check page for links
        for($l=0; $l<=count($match[2]); $l++){ //loop through links found
            $link = $match[2][$l];//url within href
            if ((strpos($link, $domain) !== false) || ($link[0]=="/")) { //check links are domain links(domain name or the first char is /)
                $updateLink = str_replace(".html", ".app", $link);//replace .html ext with .app ext
                $html = str_replace($link, $updateLink, $html); //update html with new links
            }       
        }        

    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function changeURL($url) {
    $url = str_replace('html', 'app', $url);
    return $url;
}

echo changeURL('http://www.mydomain.co.uk/page.html');
```

Result: http://www.mydomain.co.uk/page.app

Answer (score -1):

Try this, works with PHP 4 >= 4.0.5

```
<?php
    $string = "http://www.mydomain.co.uk/page.html";
    $string = preg_replace_callback("/mydomain.co.uk\/.+?(html)$/", "replace", $string);

    function replace($matches) {
        return str_replace("html", "app", $matches[0]);
    }

    echo $string;
```

Comment: While code often speaks for itself, it's good to add some explanation to your code. This popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php

// it's important to use the $ in regex to be sure to replace only the suffix and not a part of the url

function change_url($url, $find, $replace){
    return preg_replace("#\\.".preg_quote($find, "#")."$#uim", ".".$replace, $url);
    }

echo change_url("http://www.mydomain.co.uk/page.html", "html", "app");

//retuns http://www.mydomain.co.uk/page.app

?>
```